# Resample pandas dataframe and apply mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I would like to calculate mode for each group of resampled rows in pandas dataframe. I try it like so:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statistics import mode


date_times = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 5),
                           datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 5),
                           freq='D')
a = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0

frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': a},
                     index=date_times)

frame['b'] = np.random.randint(1, 3, frame.shape[0])
frame.resample("M").apply({'a':'sum', 'b':'mode'})
```

But it doesnt work.

I also try:

```
frame.resample("M").apply({'a':'sum', 'b':lambda x: mode(frame['b'])})
```

But I get wrong results. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `statistics.mode` raises a `StatisticsError` if there is more than one most-common value. What value do you want in `frame` when this situation occurs in a resampling group?

Comment: I have accepted the answer with the scipy.stats.mode solution which leads to the smallest of the two. But suppose I want the largest, how would I control it?

Comment: I don't know of a built-in function to do this. Below, I've modified my answer to show a way to do it by making a table of `value_counts`, then sorting by both the number of counts and `b` values in descending order. Then the largest `b` values in each group will be at the top when you group by dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `frame.resample("M").apply({'a':'sum', 'b':lambda x: mode(frame['b'])})` the lambda function is called once for each resampling group. `x` is assigned to a Series whose values are from the  `b` column of the resampling group.

`lambda x: mode(frame['b'])` ignores `x` and simply returns the mode of `frame['b']` -- the entire column.

Instead, you would want something like

```
frame.resample("M").apply({'a':'sum', 'b':lambda x: mode(x)})
```

However, this leads to a `StatisticsError`

```
StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values
```

since there is a resampling group with more than one most common value.

If you use `scipy.stats.mode` instead, then the smallest such most-common value is returned:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

date_times = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 5),
                           datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 5),
                           freq='D')
a = np.random.sample(date_times.size) * 10.0
frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': a}, index=date_times)
frame['b'] = np.random.randint(1, 3, frame.shape[0])

result = frame.resample("M").apply({'a':'sum', 'b':lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0]})
print(result)
```

yields

```
            b           a
2012-04-30  2  132.708704
2012-05-31  2  149.103439
2012-06-30  2  128.492203
2012-07-31  2  142.167672
2012-08-31  2  126.516689
2012-09-30  1  133.209314
2012-10-31  2  136.684212
2012-11-30  2  165.075150
2012-12-31  2  167.064212
2013-01-31  1  150.293293
2013-02-28  1  125.533830
2013-03-31  2  174.236113
2013-04-30  2   11.254136
```

---

If you want the largest most-common value, then, unfortunately, I don't know of any builtin function which does this for you. In this case you might have to compute a `value_counts` table:

```
In [89]: counts
Out[89]: 
            b  counts
2012-04-30  3      11
2012-04-30  2      10
2012-04-30  1       5
2012-05-31  2      14
2012-05-31  1       9
2012-05-31  3       8
```

Then sort it in *descending* order by both `counts` and `b` value, group by the date and take the first value in each group:

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2018)

date_times = pd.date_range(DT.datetime(2012, 4, 5), DT.datetime(2013, 4, 5), freq='D')
N = date_times.size
a = np.random.sample(N) * 10.0
frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': a, 'b': np.random.randint(1, 4, N)}, index=date_times)

resampled = frame.resample("M")
sums = resampled['a'].sum()
counts = resampled['b'].value_counts()
counts.name = 'counts'
counts = counts.reset_index(level=1)
counts = counts.sort_values(by=['counts','b'], 
                             ascending=[False,False])
result = counts.groupby(level=0).first()
```

yields

```
            b  counts
2012-04-30  3      11
2012-05-31  2      14
2012-06-30  3      12
2012-07-31  2      12
2012-08-31  2      11
2012-09-30  3      12
2012-10-31  2      13
2012-11-30  3      13
2012-12-31  2      14
2013-01-31  3      14
2013-02-28  1      10
2013-03-31  3      13
2013-04-30  3       2
```